# When bundling JavaScript with Webpack, what does the @ symbol mean at the beginning of the require/import URL?

Tags: javascript, import, require, webpack

I'm using Webpack to bundle my JavaScript application. I saw a developer during a talk that had a line similar to this:

```
var foo = require('@/foo/bar');
```

OR

```
import '@/foo/bar';
```

What does the @ symbol mean in this case? A co-worker thought that it might be a shortcut to node_modules, and it's extremely difficult to get good search results for this type of question due to ambiguity.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a specific module loader that you guys have. I don't think this is a part of webpack (but don't take my word for it, I'm unsure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` character has no special meaning in Webpack unless you configure it so. I suppose, it was a [private npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules).